# React-Nodejs app frontend does not load with docker-compose up

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a react nodejs application and it works fine running in local but when I dockerize it and run docker-compose up, the frontend webpage never loads and the backend running as expected. I am not sure where my configuration gets wrong for frontend and I would appreciate your help!

I have one dockerfile for frontend(react) and one dockerfile for backend(nodejs). I also have a docker-compose.yml file. The file structure looks like below:

```
--api(dir for backend)
 --dockerfile
--my-app(dir for frontend)
 --dockerfile
--dockercompose.yml
```

My docker file for frontend is as below:

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/my-app
COPY . .
RUN npm install && npm run build
EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My dockerfile for the backend is as below:

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /root/
COPY ./package*.json ./api/
RUN cd api && npm install
COPY ./server.js ./api/
COPY ./tracing.js ./api/
EXPOSE 3080

CMD ["node", "--require",  "./api/tracing.js",  "./api/server.js"]
```

My docker-compose file is as below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app-backend:
    build: ./api
    container_name: app-backend
    ports:
        - "3080:3080"

  app-frontend:
    depends_on:
      - app-backend
    build: ./my-app
    container_name: app-frontend
    ports:
        - "3001:3001"
    tty: true
```

This is how my frontend package.json look like:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://app-backend:3080",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

After docker-compose up, I got something like below in CLI, I don't know why it shows me port 3000, I actually set the frontend port to 3001. I tried both 3000 and 3001 in browser but neither works.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the port that a nodejs app listens on by editing `server.js` to reference a different port in its call to express.

However, its far easier to just point docker at the actual port that is being listened on, and then remap that to a desired port on the host. Given that nodejs is listening on :3000, and you want th access it on :3001 on the host, this is the proper compose.yml syntax:

```yaml
  app-frontend:
    depends_on:
      - app-backend
    build: ./my-app
    container_name: app-frontend
    ports:
        - "3001:3000"
    tty: true
```

Comment: It seems if I change the port for app-frontend in docker-compose to "3000:3000" and also in frontend docker file to Expose 3000 then  http://localhost:3000 works! With only what suggestion does not work. I am kind of new in these area, and so confused with these ports things. I would appreciate your explanation on it. I do have app.listen("3080", () => {console.log(`Server listening on the port::3080`); }); in server.js. I think the 3080 is the port server is listening on. But what do you mean by 'editing server.js to reference a different port in its call to express'? Why it calls to express?

Comment: I am also confused by the 3000/3001 in the frontend app, what does it mean? The frontend is listening on 3000/3001?

Comment: Another thing I found is as docker-compose up, I can see  http://localhost:3000 is working fine but  On Your Network:  http://192.168.48.3:3000, this url never loads, could I know what are the possible reasons for it? Thank you!

Comment: I guessed perhaps your nodejs app is using the express framework. Sorry for the confusion if not. The "3000:3000" syntax maps a port on your PC to a port in the container. If your nodejs app is listening on 3080 and you want to connect via localhost:8080, then use "8080:3080". The addresses displayed by the nodejs app show the docker network ips. Those ips are available to other containers, but not to the host or other PCs on your lan which must use your PCs hostname/ip.